# How to determine whether three ellipses have at least one common intersection point or not?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

How to establish a criterion described in equation so that it is easy to determine whether three ellipses have common intersection area (point) or not?

**Update**

[image]

[image: An exception]
[image]

Comment: I think the following would be enough. 1) Pick two of the ellipses and check that they intersect. 2) Determine which of these intersections lie on or within the third ellipse. If either step has a negative result, then the is no common area between all three.

Comment: This is not always right. Let me update with an exception.

Comment: How are the ellipses given?

Comment: suppose they are given as quadratic form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need  oracles that

(a) test for any point ${\bf p}\in{\mathbb R}^2$ and any ellipse $E$ whether ${\bf p}\in {\rm int}(E)$,

(b) compute for any ellipse $E$ its center ${\bf m}_E$,

(c) compute for any two ellipses $E_1$ and $E_2$ the set $\partial E_1\cap\partial E_2$, consisting of $0$, $2$, or $4$ points.

(Degenerate cases will not be considered.)

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be  the three given ellipses.

Compute all intersection points of two of the three boundary ellipses $\partial A$, $\partial B$, $\partial C$, using oracle (c).

If $\partial A\cap\partial B$ is empty check whether ${\bf m}_A\in B$ or ${\bf m}_B\in A$. If ${\bf m}_A\in B$ we know that $A\subset B$, so it remains to check the ellipses $A$ and $C$ versus each other. (I leave this to the OP.) – Similarly when ${\bf m}_B\in A$.

Similarly when $\partial B\cap\partial C$ or $\partial C\cap\partial A$ is empty.

Assume now that any two boundary ellipses $\partial A$, $\partial B$, $\partial C$ intersect. Then we apply the following Lemma and oracle (a):

**Lemma.** The set $\Omega:={\rm int}(A\cap B\cap C)$ is nonempty **iff** at least one  intersection point of two boundary ellipses  lies in the interior of the third ellipse.

*Proof.* Any neighborhood of ${\bf r}\in\partial A\cap\partial B$ contains points of ${\rm int}(A\cap B)$. When ${\bf r}$ lies in ${\rm int}(C)$ the set $\Omega$ is nonempty.

For the proof of the converse consider the following "Gedankenexperiment": We pick a point ${\bf p}\in \Omega$ and draw a ray from ${\bf p}$ to infinity that does not go through any intersection point of two boundary ellipses. This ray will hit a first boundary ellipse, say $\partial A$, in a point ${\bf q}$. The point ${\bf q}$ is still in the interior of both $B$ and $C$. Now walk from ${\bf q}$ along $\partial A$ until you hit for the first time a point of $\partial A\cap\partial B$ or $\partial A\cap\partial C$. Assume this is  the point ${\bf r}\in\partial A\cap\partial B$, say. This point ${\bf r}$ is still in the interior of $C$.

Comment: Neat solution! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @ Semiclassical comment, I got one answer:

1. suppose three ellipse are $a$, $b$ and $c$; so there are three combinations if we draw two from the three: $(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)$
2. test the number of interaction points between $(a,b), (a,c),\text{ or } (b,c)$, if the number is $0$, there is no common point between the three; if the number is $1$, then if the only point is not in or on the third ellipse,  there is no common point between the three;
3. for the cases when interaction points between all the combinations are more than or equal to $2$ ($\leqslant 4$), test if there is any intersection point in/on the third ellipse; if all are no, then they have no common point; if any is yes, then the three ellipses have common interaction points.

This still has exception case:

[image]

**Update**

1. suppose three ellipse are $a$, $b$ and $c$; so there are three combinations if we draw two from the three: $(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)$
2. test the number of interaction points between $(a,b), (a,c),\text{ or } (b,c)$,

   2.1 if the number is $0$, check whether one ellipse is totally contained by another; if no, there is no common point between the three; if yes, the problem becomes determine whether the small ellipse and the third have common point or not; check  the existence of intersection point and the containing relationship between the two;

   2.2 if the number is $1$, then if the only point is not in or on the third ellipse,  there is no common point between the three;
3. for the cases when interaction points between all the combinations are more than or equal to $2$ ($\leqslant 4$), test if there is any intersection point in/on the third ellipse; if all are no, then they have no common point; if any is yes, then the three ellipses have common interaction points.

Comment: The ellipses don't have to intersect at all for them to have a common area. They could be nested one inside the other.